# MySQL ERROR 2002 (HY000) on CentOS 5

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I have problem with starting up mysql. When I type

```
service mysql start
```

All I got is

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)**

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo service mysql start`? What does `service mysqld status` say? Or `mysqladmin -u root -p status`. Also: How did you configure MySQL in `my.cnf`? Has it ever worked before?

Comment: sudo service mysql start says 

audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused
mysql: unrecognized service

Comment: What about the other questions of mine?

Comment: Wait -- isn't the service called "mysqld" (with a trailing "d" for "daemon")? that would explain the "unrecognized service mysql", right? So try: `sudo service mysqld start` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First check the status of the service

> [root@localhost ~]# service mysqld status
>
> mysqld is stopped

```
[root@localhost ~]# su - max
Password:
```

If service is stop, that time you are getting these type of error

```
 
[max@localhost ~]$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Now start the service

```
[max@localhost ~]$ su -
Password: 
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
```

Now check the status of the service

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid  6157) is running...
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# exit
logout
```

```
[max@localhost ~]$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.1.61 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```