# UBUNTU 14.04 Locked out of MYSQL, unable to get back in with root or other user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have read every instruction I could find on the web to re-enable root in mysqld without success.  So, I had a bright idea.  I uninstalled mysql, thinking I could start from scratch.  So I uninstalled it as follows:

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql-client mysql-server
```

Then I reinstalled it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

But at this point I get an error so I could not get down to the next line

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

The current error is:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I read up on it and it mentions the `my.cnf` file, but my `/etc/mysql` directory no longer exists.  I used to see it before and it had that file before... but the directory and all the subdirectories and files are gone...

Please help...

Comment: Did you read [this question's answer](https://superuser.com/a/492672/425048), which may help you determine if mysqld is running?

Comment: ender.qa Yes and here is what I get when I run it: (   service mysql start   )
    #  start: Job failed to start

Comment: Basically, the mysqld program (that daemon that runs in the background) did not start. You will need to look in your logs to see if there are any messages on why the program did not start. Try looking in `/var/log/syslog`. There may be other logs in `/var/log` that are helpful.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you have no files in `/etc/mysql`, which doesn't seem right. Are you sure that mysql-server has been installed correctly? Try running `sudo apt install -f` to 'fix' any problems. Lastly, you can try to start 'mysqld' manually. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179568/4635198) may be of help.

Comment: I am pretty certain that there is a problem and that directory contains vital data 
  When I run  dmesg | less    I get :       
[ 4296.143626] init: mysql pre-start process (1432) terminated with status 1

Comment: Is there any other way than to reinstall ubuntu from scratch?    Why are those directories not regenerated when I uninstall and reinstall.  It seems that they are created by the UBUNTU install...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92057/discussion-between-ender-qa-and-dekoss).

Answer (score 0):

The missing directory is the problem, so I reinstalled UBUNTU 14.04 and it came back.  That was the only way I could find to restore `mysqld` .  Sorry that I could not be any more useful.  The good side is that I learned more about UBUNTU installation...

Regards,
DK